# VS2010 Server Explorer Data Connections: where are they registered or stored? How do I edit them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We changed a database server and as a consequence, all the Data Connections point to a wrong server.
I want to edit them to change the server, but the only thing I can do is delete and re-create them. Not nice.

**Where are their definition stored so I can change them?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the file where they are stored: It's `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView`, but the ConnectionStrings are encrypted, so you can't change them :(

In VS15 it's `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView`,  but ConnectionStrings are still encrypted

Comment: For anyone searching for this recently: 

VS 2019: %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_[BuildNumber]\ServerExplorer